# Reformatting the labels in fitch.sty proofs

Tags: fitch

Out of the box, the `fitch.sty` package (the one now maintained by Richard Zach, available [here](https://ctan.org/pkg/fitch)) has some automatic labeling behavior, and I'd like to change it.

1. I'd like to put parentheses around the line numbers. Out of the box, they're just bare numbers.
2. I'd like to eliminate the comma right after the name of the rule mentioned in the justification of inference steps.

You can see the out-of-the box behavior in the MWE below.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{fitch}
\begin{document}

\begin{displaymath}
  \begin{nd}
    \hypo {1} {(P \land (Q \land R))} %
    \hypo {2} {(S \land P')}%
    \have {3} {(Q \land R)} \ae{1}%
    \have {4} {Q} \ae{3} %
    \have {5} {P'} \ae{2}%
    \have {6} {(P' \land Q)} \ai{5,4}
  \end{nd}
\end{displaymath}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the MWE Code]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will be able to do this in v1.0; see section 4 of the documentation: https://github.com/OpenLogicProject/fitch/releases/tag/v1.0-beta (Edit: I wrote too soon. You can't yet configure how numbers are printed. But that'd be easy to do.)

Update: done in https://github.com/OpenLogicProject/fitch/releases/tag/v1.0-beta2

In the new version of `fitch`, you can just put into the preamble:

```
\renewcommand{\ndjustformat}[2]{#1 #2}
\renewcommand{\ndrefformat}[1]{(#1)}
```

Comment: Will this version be pushed to CTAN soon?

Comment: It is not 100% backwards compatible and needs some testing, but soon-ish

Answer (score 1):

What at strangely written package. It certainly makes simple modifications like these harder than needed by using `*` as the internal command character instead of `@`.  I've also changed the document class to `article` because your code doesn't compile for me with `standalone`. (It seems that the beta version available on GitHub has fixed this problem.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
%
\usepackage{fitch}
% begin fitch modifications
{\chardef\x=\catcode`\*
\catcode`\*=11
\global\let\nd*astcode\x}
\catcode`\*=11

\patchcmd{\nd*by}{,}{}{}{\fail}
\patchcmd{\nd*render}{\the\nd*ctr}{(\the\nd*ctr)}{}{\fail}

\catcode`\*=\nd*astcode
% end fitch modifications
% don't try to do anything else within this block of code!

\begin{document}

\begin{displaymath}
  \begin{nd}
    \hypo {1} {(P \land (Q \land R))} %
    \hypo {2} {(S \land P')}%
    \have {3} {(Q \land R)} \ae{1}%
    \have {4} {Q} \ae{3} %
    \have {5} {P'} \ae{2}%
    \have {6} {(P' \land Q)} \ai{5,4}
  \end{nd}
\end{displaymath}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

### Update: using the pre-release version

If you download the pre-release version of the updated package available [here](https://github.com/OpenLogicProject/fitch) you can use the following to do the same thing. The new version has also undone the strange use of `*` in the code and replaced it with `@`.

```
\renewcommand{\ndjustformat}[2]{#1 #2}
\renewcommand{\ndrefformat}[1]{(#1)}
```

Comment: It is very strange. I looked up LaTeX for Logicians to see if there was a better option, but didn't find anything. (There are better packages, but the style differs.)